# Plots in R vs Summary of model

Tags: r, regression

So I'm using R to understand my dataset. I'm getting slightly confused since I have got an Adjusted R square of around 3% (which is clearly super low- so guessing my model isn't good). But then when i plot the model, I get the below two pictures which to me seem a good fit? The red line in the residuals plot shows it's close enough to 0- which indicates good? and The Q graph shows a normal distribution fit?

[image]

[image]

thanks for all your help in advance!

Comment: Look at the scale on your residual plot. It appears to me that your errors (residuals) are much bigger than the values that you are predicting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know what the red line represents/shows in that first picture?

Comment: I think that it is a loess curve fit to the data. In your case, that curve seems to say that the errors do not (on average) vary much the fitted value. This confirms what you saw in your QQ plot. The errors are nicely distributed,  just too big.

Comment: What are your data (specifically the response)? Why do they seem to stop at 0? Your qq-plot shows a clear deviation from normality at the lower tail.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the shape of your residual plot is good - nicely balanced around zero. However, look at the scales on the axes. Most of your fitted values range from 0 to 250. The residuals are mostly in the range from -1100 to +1100, i.e. the errors are about four times as big as the values that you are predicting. R-squared = 3% seems reasonable with such big errors.

Also, to address your other question from the comments, the red line is a loess curve fitted to the residuals.  In your case, the curve is close to y=0 which says that on average, your results are good. But again, having one error of +500 and another of -500 may average to zero error, but does not indicate a good result.

Answer (score 1):

You're conflating two ways that a regression can be "good".

Low $R^2$ means that there's low correlation. That is, that the trendline doesn't provide much better prediction than just the sample average for the outcome.

Reasonably calibrated QQ plot and lack of trend in the plot of predicted vs residuals just means that the data are kind of normal.